# Complex constraints using OR Tools in Python for a scheduling problem

Tags: python, constraints, or-tools

I'm trying to use the OR Tools library to solve a scheduling problem in Python, and it's really similar to the nurse scheduling solved in their [blog](https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling). The only difference is that I can't model shifts with an id, I have to write the minute the shift starts and the minute the shift ends. You can think of it like nurses have to work in 3 different works, and each one has its shifts written in a calendar.

I want to write the constraint that there aren't any nurses working in different shifts from different works with intersecting intervals. The problem is that my attempts have used ifs, and it seems this isn't a good way to define a constraint.

```
# The total number of shifts each person has at each moment has to be less than one
for p in people:
    for r in roles_per_person[p]:
        for h in range(len(hours_per_role[r])-1):
            sum_other_roles = sum(shifts[(p, hours_per_role[r2][h2], hours_per_role[r2][h2+1], r2)] for r2 in roles_per_person[p] for h2 in range(len(hours_per_role[r2])-1) if (hours_per_role[r2][h2+1] > hours_per_role[r][h] and hours_per_role[r][h+1] > hours_per_role[r2][h2]))
            model.AddImplication(shifts[(p, hours_per_role[r][h], hours_per_role[r][h+1], r)] == 1, sum_other_roles <= 0)
```

I can't think of any way of doing it right, and I don't really understand the [sofisticated example](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py) they have about more complex constraints. Any advice would be helpful, even if it's just about how to define complex constraints. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Little example of what I mean:
[image]

Comment: Consider using a more scheduling-like approach using Intervals and NoOverlap constraints. Generally you can easily express stuff like person A has to do `X` shifts, each being within `[start, end)` without overlap (see job shop examples and co.). If needed, you can also express *optional* shifts when `X` is not constant a-priori. See the gate scheduling example. Sadly it's hard to grasp what you are trying to achieve in detail, so that's just a recommendation for some research-direction.This is probably only a good idea if shifts are diverse and can't be compressed into a limited amount of ids

Comment: @sascha Okay thank you!, I'll try to see if I can change the constraints to that. In my actual problem there are eight roles, two of them with a particular "shift calendar", and the other six with another. I could make ids about each one, but after that I still have to check the constraint about "No one can work at the same time for two roles", and for that I need the intervals, isn't it?

Comment: It's hard to help here. The description is very far away from a formal model. But with id-based shifts, in most models `No one can work at the same time for two roles` is just a bound on some row or column. If the columns are time-shifts, the rows are person-role encodings like `row 0: p0r0, row 1: p0r1 ... row 7: p0r7 row 8: p1r0`, non-overlapping collapses into `nShift` linear-constraints like `sum(p0r0, ...p0r7) <= 1` (a trimmed column-sum; non-overlapping in shift 0 = column 0 for person 0 over all roles = rows 0..7). Of course these things always depends on the modelling style.

Comment: Would something like `sum(overlapping assignments) <= 1` work? If I am not mistaken you don't really have intervals as the shifts times are already computed, but yeah, I don't really understand the problem description very well either

Comment: @sascha It seems I'm not explaining it properly, so I've made a little image to show an example of what I'm trying to model and my problem. https://imgur.com/QdWjvg7

Each square is a particular shift in a particular role. Each role has its own shift calendar, by that I mean the tasks have different time intervals. I can't make column sums because the shift 3 in role 0 may not be in the same time than shift 3 in role 2.

Comment: @Stradivari That could work. I don't know if maybe there are too many overlapping possibilities, but I'll try, thanks for the recommendation. Also, I've made an edit with an image showing an example so it's a bit clearer, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If those shifts are static / a-priori known: just build a conflict-set of overlapping shifts. This is just the generalization of those column-sums described above. In the easy approach, those are conflict-pairs (not a or not b). For the more curious: this can be mapped to a (interval-)graph which is guaranteed to  be chordal which implies that the calculation of all maximal cliques is doable in polynomial-time (e.g. with networkx). <= 1 for each maximal clique allows stronger propagation (convex hull) than those pairs.

Comment: @sascha Okay that sounds perfect, thanks! I knew about networkx and I've worked with interval graphs before but didn't clicked the connection here, so thank you, I'll do that.